# How to update Critic Network when training PPO algorithm?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Now I am debugging a reinforcement learning (PPO) algorithm, when I looked at some codes in Github, some people update their Critic network by using MSE(R(t),V(st)),where R(t) is cumulative rewards, but there are also some people using MSE(V(st),r(t)+V(s+1)),which one is correct? Or they are both correct?

Could you please tell me the mathematic meaning of using MSE(R(t),V(st))?